# Creating appropriate dataset for tensorflow multilabel classification model: "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I'm trying to train a multiclass image classification model, based on this model:

https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/5

And taking some code from here:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_image_retraining.ipynb#scrollTo=umB5tswsfTEQ

My model is created like this:

```
model_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v3_large_075_224/feature_vector/5"  

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Explicitly define the input shape so the model can be properly
    # loaded by the TFLiteConverter
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + (3,)),
    hub.KerasLayer(model_url, trainable=do_fine_tuning),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(class_names),
                          kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001))
])

model.build((None,) + IMAGE_SIZE + (3,))
model.summary()

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.005, momentum=0.9),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True, label_smoothing=0.1),
    metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My data is coming from a datagenerator, which is pulling data from a MongoDB database. The datagenerator `__data_generation` looks like:

```
def __data_generation(self, list_paths, list_paths_wo_ext):
    'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
    # Initialization
    num_items = min(self.batch_size, len(list_paths))
    x = np.empty((num_items, self.target_size[1], self.target_size[0], 3))

    y = np.empty((num_items,))

    # Generate data
    for i, ID in enumerate(list_paths):
        # Store sample
        img = Image.open(ID)  # type: Image
        img.load()  # required for png.split()

        if os.path.isfile(resize_cache_path):## Heading ##
            resized = Image.open(resize_cache_path)
            resized.load()
        else:
            resized = img.resize(self.target_size)
            resized.save(resize_cache_path)
        x[i, ] = resized
        y[i, ] = self.targets.loc[ID].values

    return x, y
```

On `y[i, ] = self.targets.loc[ID].values` I'm getting a `ValueError` however.

The plot thickened when I downwnloaded a sample dataset as used by the colab:

```
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'flower_photos',
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
    untar=True)

IMAGE_SIZE = (224, 224)

data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'flower_photos',
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
    untar=True)


def build_dataset(subset):
    return tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        data_dir,
        validation_split=.20,
        subset=subset,
        label_mode="categorical",
        # Seed needs to provided when using validation_split and shuffle = True.
        # A fixed seed is used so that the validation set is stable across runs.
        seed=123,
        image_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
        batch_size=1)
    
    
    train_ds = build_dataset("training")
    
    for x, y in train_ds.as_numpy_iterator():
        print(y)
```

This prints a result like:

[[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]

I didn't know how this applied to the multilabel scenario so I ran the following code:

```
for x, y in train_ds.as_numpy_iterator():
    total = sum(y[0])
    if total > 1:
        print(total)
```

There was no output, so it appears either I've misunderstood or this dataset simply isn't multilabel.

My question is, how can I create a custom multilabel dataset from my own database for consumption the model listed above?

Comment: Usually errors like this arise when trying to make a tensor from a non-numeric array.  If the array (or list) contains arrays that vary in size, the dtype will be object, and trying to make `np.array(..., dtype=float)` produces this error.

Answer (score 0):

`On y[i, ] = self.targets.loc[ID].values I'm getting a ValueError however.`

What does the error say? `setting an array element with a sequence`?
In that case you might want to initialize `y` explicitly as a matrix via `y = np.empty((num_items, len(class_names)))`. `self.targets.loc[ID].values` should then be a vector of length `len(class_names)` which is 0 everywhere except for the indices that indicate the classes to which the input sample with `ID` belongs.

`There was no output, so it appears either I've misunderstood or this dataset simply isn't multilabel.`

The dataset is not multilabel since each input image is only assigned to one of the 5 flower classes (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images). Thus, there is no output in your loop since the sum of `y[0]` is always exactly 1.